# Dropdown not picking items from the options list

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently I have a form tag in my page that contains different input and select tags. I have 2 problems with my select tag. First is that for some reason it does not pick any of the items that I'm trying to select.
And second, I want to show a placeholder on the dropdown which matches the font of the other input placeholders in my form, but it shows my placeholder which is my first item in the dropdownlist as a plain text.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cdn-lpv8m?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
<div class="container" style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECECEC" }}>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12">
              
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-12 mx-auto">
              <form>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        name="fname"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Last Name"
                        name="lname"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <select
                    value="Nationality"
                    className="form-control contactInput dropdown"
                    placeholder="Nationality"
                  >
                    <option value="" readonly="true" hidden="true" selected>
                      Nationality
                    </option>
                    <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
                    <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
                    <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
                    
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                      <select
                        value="Country"
                        className="form-control contactInput dropdown"
                        placeholder="Country"
                      >
                        <option value="" readonly="true" hidden="true" selected>
                      Country of Residence
                    </option>
                        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                        <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
                        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        name="email"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Phone"
                        name="phone"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Family Situation"
                        name="email"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <select value="Nationality"
                    className="form-control contactInput dropdown"
                    placeholder="Nationality"><option value="1">1</option></select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <textarea
                    class="form-control contactInput"
                    placeholder="Message"
                    rows="4"
                    name="message"
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
                <input
                  class="form-control contactInput"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#0E2043",
                    color: "#fff",
                    textAlign: "center",
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  value="Submit"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Reference of what I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your second thing?

Comment: @TechySharnav I have added a reference image. Here you can see my dropdowns placeholders have a specific color that matches the other placeholders. But here I cant achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `class` with `className` attribute, also remove the `value` attribute from your `<select>` element. This attribute is what is preventing the selected option to be displayed.

CSS for the second part (placeholder):

```
/* To target all <select> */
select option[value=""] { color: #ccc }

/* To target specific E.g.: <select id="country" ...> */
select#country option[value=""] { color: #ccc }
```

Add an "id" attribute to your country dropdown like below:

```
<select id="country" ...>
```

Comment: Yes this worked, can you also help me with the second part of my quetion

Comment: Sure, please update your codesanbox with the latest code. You just need the appropriate classes for aligning items to match your reference image. A <select> element does not support `placeholder` attribute. So you just need to style the default option with CSS.

Comment: This actually changes the color for all my options in list. I want only the 1st placeholder value to be a different color

Comment: Yes, I just provided a reference how you can change colors. You can use the CSS "#" selector to target whichever `<select>` you want. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You were setting `value="..."` on `select` element, which resulted it being default value, and not changing.
A workaround is to create a disabled `option` element, and make it selected by default.

Also, React uses `className` instead of `class`. So you need to replace all occurrences of `class` with `className`.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section
        className="section-padding"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECECEC" }}
        id="about"
      >
        <div className="container" style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECECEC" }}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12">
              
            </div>

            <div className="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-12 mx-auto">
              <form>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        name="fname"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Last Name"
                        name="lname"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <select
                    className="form-control contactInput dropdown"
                    placeholder="Nationality"
                  >
                    <option disabled value="" readonly="true" selected>
                      Nationality
                    </option>
                    <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
                    <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
                    <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
                    
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                      <select
                        className="form-control contactInput dropdown"
                        placeholder="Country"
                      >
                        <option disabled value="" readonly="true"  selected>
                      Country of Residence
                    </option>
                        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                        <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
                        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        name="email"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Phone"
                        name="phone"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control contactInput"
                        placeholder="Family Situation"
                        name="email"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <select value="Nationality"
                    className="form-control contactInput dropdown"
                    placeholder="Nationality"><option value="1">1</option></select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control contactInput"
                    placeholder="Message"
                    rows="4"
                    name="message"
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
                <input
                  className="form-control contactInput"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#0E2043",
                    color: "#fff",
                    textAlign: "center",
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  value="Submit"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-archimedes-m6d28?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your value as a string: "Nationality". This does not reference your drop down beforehand. You could use php to set the value via POST to get the old value of itself.

`value=<?php $_POST['idOfNationality']; ?>`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

CodeSandbox:https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-tharp-1t2p0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

use can also use react hooks for this (useState)
const [nationality, setNationality] = useState('afghan');

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to change **class** to **className**.

and **select** tag **value** need to be attached to the state like this(called a controlled component):

```
 <select
                value={nationality}
                className="form-control contactInput dropdown"
                placeholder="Nationality"
                onChange={handleChangeNationnality}
              >
```

and add a disabled **option** like this:

```
<option value="disabled" disabled className="disabledOption">
  nationality
</option>
```

then add some css:

```
.disabledOption {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

and you add **useState** like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [nationality, setNationality] = useState("disabled");
```

like this, your state is always refering to **selected option**.

and, don't forget to add a callback handler like this:

```
 function handleChangeNationnality(e: any) {
 setNationality((nationality) => e.target.value);
 }
```

with this now your you select value can be changed.
i encouraged you to look at this in docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

**select** tag from **hmtl5** is different from react **select** tag, and the reason is(from react docs): this makes it so that **input**, **textarea**, and **select** all work very similarly - they all accept a value attribute that you can use to implement a controlled component.

here is what i did in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sky-7h9ms?file=/src/App.tsx:160-261